# Flex 3 passing objects from Flex to java class

Tags: apache-flex, remoting

I want to pass an object from my Flex application back to my Java app. Im looking at either passing to a Serlet or passing via a DAO as an object.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you connecting to java? are you using AMF?

Generally speaking, passing as an object would be the best solution overall because you probably will be using that object in your flex application anyway.

Comment: at the moment im using web services component or httpservice to connect to java. I want to pass the object to my webservice to do an update on my table. do you recommend AMF for this?

Comment: I would.  Like dirk mentions, look at remote objects and optionally you could look at LCDS for connecting flex to java. Either way, connecting to the dao directly seems like the best choice.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Adobe's BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/) . It provides the middleware to pass objects from flex to java, and vice-versa. It lets you use the RemoteObject and Messaging abstractions in flex.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that they renamed it BlazeDS; this is what I was talking about when I said LCDS

Answer (score 1):

Look at [RemoteObjects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html).

Comment: D'oh! Sorry about the mixup. Fixed now.